# Write a query which will show all employees whose last names start with "M" and have an 'ae' anywhere in their last name

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to write it like this.

```
WHERE LastName LIKE 'M%'
```

but did not complete all

Comment: "but did not complete all" Can you elaborate? I don't understand "did not complete all".

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like:

`select LastName from people where LastName like "M%ae%"`

Each `%` is a wild card for an unknown number of unknown letters.

(Replace `people` with the name of the relevant table, and the first occurrence of LastName with the information you want from the table)